# python google search by location and time

Tags: python, search

Trying to get the source from google searches that use the advanced search tools (by location, window of time, etc..).  I can scrap the context of a page using lynx or urlib but it doesn't take into account the advanced search options, anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to do that the Custom Search API can't accomplish?

Comment: The custom search api is not free.

Comment: So far, I think it is going to have to be a bash script, or python script using the lynx ablity to save to file the keystroke commands and then read the keystroke commands. Does any know at what rate google will begin blocking my ip?